# What's the declination for snabel-a?

Tags: swedish

What's the declination for

```
Ett snabel-a
```

i.e. the name for the symbol @?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [SAOB](http://www.saob.se/so/visa.php?id=1652102314), *snabel-a* is quite regular: like other letters of the alphabet, abbreviations, etc., a colon is used to separate the stem from its desinences, and the forms are:

> *ett snabel-a* | *ett snabel-a:s*
>   *snabel-a:et* | *snabel-a:ets*
>   *snabel-a* | *snabel-a:s*   **or**   *snabel-a:n* | *snabel-a:ns*
>   *snabel-a:na* | *snabel-a:nas*

(Though some of those strike me as being highly unlikely to ever be used; indefinite plural possessives are rare in general, and I don't believe I've personally ever had any need to use one with the word *snabel-a* at all.)